# Run multiple just rules in parallel

Tags: just

I would like to run all dependent rules in my [`justfile`](https://just.systems/man/en/chapter_1.html) to run in parallel. How do I do this?

```
pull-all: pull-a pull-b

pull-a:
    docker pull a

pull-b:
    docker pull b
```

When I run `just pull-all`, just runs the two dependents `pull-a` and `pull-b` sequentially, in the order they are listed after `pull-all:`.

Is there a way to tell `just` to run both of them at the same time in parallel?

I looked at the documentation but couldn't find any mention of "parallel" and only one mention of "order".

Answer (score 0):

It is not yet supported, but there is a [feature request](https://github.com/casey/just/issues/626) (and an [open PR](https://github.com/casey/just/pull/1562)).

Two other things that you may want to investigate:

- https://github.com/Nukesor/pueue
- https://taskfile.dev/usage/#task-dependencies